# Transferring files between 2 remote linux virtual machines

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, scp

Me and my friend are trying to transfer files remotely using scp. We have both installed ssh server and turned it online but when trying to use the command nothing happens.
I am trying to transfer using his public ip.
It says it is listening on port 22, but I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: We need way more information to even start troubleshooting this.Give use OS's/Distros at least  First try sshing from one of the boxes into itself. (Does that work yes or no? His public IP are you natting port 22 back to his private addess? As well are you running firewalls that would stop traffic.

Comment: I disabled the firewall and the machine can ssh to itself. However we are relatively new to Linux and don't know how to nat the port back to his private adress

Comment: Okay do you have access to the router?

Comment: I do, but is it also possible by the port forwarding tab in the virtual box settings?

Comment: Don't worry about that, setup the port forwarding on the receiving FW and forward port 22 to the private IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things:

1. Make sure in VirtualBox the network of the VM is set to `bridged` (you need to shut down the VM for this first). This will make the VM appear as a separate computer on the network, and make connecting to it more transparent.
2. Check the IP address of the VM (e.g. by running `ip a` inside the VM in a terminal)
3. Login to the web interface of your router and add a *port forward* to the IP you found and port 22.

Now you should be able to login from a remote host with `ssh` on your **external** IP (**not** the same as the VM's IP!).